# Series voltage and voltage tester module

Tags: voltage, batteries, series, tester

I have a question about battery tester module.  I have in my hands a board that shows the capacity of a 3.7V 18650 LiPo, presumably by measuring voltage.  It has 4 LEDs on it.

If I hook this up to the + and - of a single cell in a series of cells (say, 3 cells), will that voltage always be of the single cell, regardless of whether there is current flowing, as long as it is connected to the single cell ? I mean, if there is current flowing through the series, and the voltage is 11.1V through the batteries, will this cause the board to blow up ?

The board can only handle up to 4.5V.

Comment: Thanks annie ! The project is for a portable drill, i am replacing the nicad batteries with lipo cells and a bms board.  Good to know the voltage meter will work correctly with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you connect your battery tester across a single cell, it will only measure the voltage of that cell, regardless of how many cells are connected in series with it.